# How to run a zero downtime application in kubernetes StatefulSet

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset

I would like to run a stateful application (performs read/ write operations into a specific folder) in Kubernetes without a single instance dependency.

1. Can I use statefulset for this requirement.
2. Is it necessary to use a shared file system (eg: GFS, EFS...)?
3. If yes, does it affect my application's performance.

Comment: Answer will depend on factors like, a. is that folder shared b/w applications? b. Do multiple instances of same container require to access same folder or they can have their own local copy? Do you need sharding in this use-case?

Comment: Yes, I need sharing. But if a use a dedicated volume (eg: EBS), will lead a single point of failure. If I use EFS/ GFS, does it cause any performance issues.? or is there any other options I can use in this scenario.?

Comment: Will a NFS exposed as volume suit your use-case?